# Picker view is not changing when you try to select a different option in swiftui

Tags: swiftui, pickerview

I am using in swiftUI. When select picker, it is not changing. Here is code..

Here is datamodel:

```
struct SourceAccountModel:Codable,Identifiable{
var id: Int
let accountNumber: String
let accountTitle: String
let priaryAccount: String

init(id:Int=0,accountNumber: String, accountTitle: String, priaryAccount: String) {
    self.id = id
   self.accountNumber = accountNumber
   self.accountTitle = accountTitle
   self.priaryAccount = priaryAccount
  
   }
}
```

1. Here is my code

   ```
     struct Test2: View {
       @State private var selectedOption = "Option 1"
       @State private var sourceAccountList = [SourceAccountModel]()
       var body: some View {
           VStack{
               ZStack {
                   RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                       .fill(Color.white)
                       .shadow(radius: 2)
                   Picker(selection: $selectedOption,label: EmptyView()) {

                       ForEach (0..<sourceAccountList.count,id: \.self) {
                           Text(sourceAccountList[$0].accountNumber)
                       }

                   }
                   .padding(8)
               }
               .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
           }.onAppear{
               intitializeValue()
           }
       }
       func intitializeValue(){

           self.sourceAccountList.append(SourceAccountModel(id:1,accountNumber: "Option 1", accountTitle: "", priaryAccount: ""))
           self.sourceAccountList.append(SourceAccountModel(id:2,accountNumber: "Option 2", accountTitle: "", priaryAccount: ""))


       }
   }
   ```

Always select first value. What is the wrong with my code?

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`selectedOption` is a `String`, but your `ForEach` iterates over `Range<Int>`.

You can fix this by changing `selectedOption` to `Int`, e.g.

```
@State private var selectedOption = 0
```

You might find it easier to store the actual object in `selectedOption: SourceAccountModel`, iterate over the `sourceAccountList`, and tag each row:

```
struct SourceAccountModel: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: Int
    let accountNumber: String
    
    init(id: Int, accountNumber: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.accountNumber = accountNumber
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
        let sourceAccountList = [SourceAccountModel(id: 1, accountNumber: "Option 1"),
                                 SourceAccountModel(id: 2, accountNumber: "Option 2")]
        
        _sourceAccountList = State(wrappedValue: sourceAccountList)
        _selectedOption = State(wrappedValue: sourceAccountList[0])
    }
    
    @State private var selectedOption: SourceAccountModel
    @State private var sourceAccountList = [SourceAccountModel]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker("Select", selection: $selectedOption) {
                ForEach(sourceAccountList) { model in
                    Text(model.accountNumber).tag(model)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```